# Property "roles" in "App\Domain\Entities\User" was already declared, but it must be declared only once error

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

I have met this error in my `User.php`. I found two ways to fix it, one way is delete `protected $roles` but by using this way, it not create foreign key anymore. The other way is delete `@ACL\HasRoles()` but I think do this will disable Doctrine ACL. Do you have any idea to fix this error but still create foreign key in my database?
User.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Domain\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use LaravelDoctrine\ACL\Roles\HasRoles;
use LaravelDoctrine\ACL\Mappings as ACL;
use LaravelDoctrine\ACL\Contracts\HasRoles as HasRolesContract;

/** @ORM\Entity() */
class User implements HasRolesContract
{
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column (type="guid", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     * @ACL\HasRoles()
     * @var ArrayCollection|\LaravelDoctrine\ACL\Contracts\Role[]
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column (type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column (type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column (type="string", length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = roles;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }
}
```

Role.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Domain\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use LaravelDoctrine\ACL\Contracts\Permission;
use LaravelDoctrine\ACL\Contracts\Role as RoleContract;

/** @ORM\Entity() */
class Role implements RoleContract
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column (type="guid", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column (type="string", length=50, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function hasPermissionTo($permission)
    {
        // TODO: Implement hasPermissionTo() method.
    }

    public function getPermissions()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getPermissions() method.
    }
}
```

This is sql query generate from entity when I delete `@ACL\HasRoles()`:

```
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE roles (id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:guid)\', name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_B63E2EC75E237E06 (name), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');

$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE users (id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:guid)\', first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E9E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

This is sql query generate from entity when I delete `protected $roles`:

```
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE roles (id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:guid)\', name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_B63E2EC75E237E06 (name), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
        
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE users (id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:guid)\', first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E9E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
        
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE users_roles (user_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:guid)\', role_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:guid)\', INDEX IDX_51498A8EA76ED395 (user_id), INDEX IDX_51498A8ED60322AC (role_id), PRIMARY KEY(user_id, role_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
        
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE users_roles ADD CONSTRAINT FK_51498A8EA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
        
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE users_roles ADD CONSTRAINT FK_51498A8ED60322AC FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huray, I have fixed this error. I don't know the reason but If I remove this code in my `User.php` then I can run `php artisan doctrine:migrations:diff` again and it also create an association class and foreign key for me.

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
```

I think the reason because `@ACL\HasRoles()` and `@var ArrayCollection|\LarvaelDoctrine\ACL\Contracts\Role[]` automatically find my Role class and create a schema for me. Then I don't need `@ORM\ManyToMany` anymore.